# Vertically aligning text inside a button using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to have a class that should make `anchor` and `button` tag, appear the same whenever I assigned them in a class,

I am using flexbox to handle media object for me like so:

```
.media {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: start;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
    -moz-box-align: start;
    -ms-flex-align: start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
 }
.media--center {
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.media__fig {}
.media__bd {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1 0 0;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1 0 0;
    flex: 1 0 0;
}
```

The problem is, that it does not appear the same and does not align the same. Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WTf9e/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, a few things:

(1) The `display: inline-block` in your testcase has no effect, because it's superceded by the `display:flex` that appears later and applies to the same elements with the same specificity. That's why the `<a>` element ends up being the width of the page -- its `display:flex` makes it block-level, which means its auto-width stretches to fill the available space.  If you want your elements to be inline-level, you should be using `display:inline-flex` instead of `flex`. (and drop the `inline-block` styling since it gets overridden anyway)

(2) You're setting `display:flex` directly on a `<button>` (by assigning the "media" class to it), and that [doesn't work in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=984869#c2) -- buttons only react to their `display` value so far as respecting whether they're inline-level vs. block-level. (As noted in that bug page, Chrome has similar behavior on other special elements like `<table>` and `<fieldset>`, though it does happen to accept custom 'display' styling on `<button>` for some reason. Firefox does not, in any case.)  To fix this, you need to set `display:flex` on a wrapper-div *inside* of the `<button>`, instead of on the `<button>` itself. (or, in addition to the `<button>` itself)

(3) You probably need the wrapper-div inside the `<button>` to have 100% height and 100% width, or else it will get some auto-centering-in-both-dimensions behavior that buttons automatically perform on their children (and which isn't exposed via CSS). Maybe you don't need this, but I imagine this would present a difference in behavior between `<a>` and `<button>`.